# Replicate logistic regression model from pyspark in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pyspark

**Problem:** The default implementations (no custom parameters set) of the logistic regression model in pyspark and scikit-learn seem to yield different results given their default paramter values.

I am trying to replicate a result from logistic regression (no custom paramters set) performed with pypark (see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression) with the logistic regression model from scikit-learn (see: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

It appears to me that both model implementations (in pyspark and scikit) do not possess the same parameters, so i cant just simply match the paramteres in scikit to fit those in pyspark. Is there any solution on how to match both models on their default configuration?

Parameters Scikit model (default parameters):

```
`LogisticRegression(
C=1.0, 
class_weight=None, 
dual=False, 
fit_intercept=True,
intercept_scaling=1, 
max_iter=100, 
multi_class='ovr', 
n_jobs=1,
penalty='l2', 
random_state=None, 
solver='liblinear', 
tol=0.0001,
verbose=0, 
warm_start=False`
```

Parameters Pyspark model (default parameters):

```
LogisticRegression(self, 
featuresCol="features", 
labelCol="label", 
predictionCol="prediction", 
maxIter=100,
regParam=0.0, 
elasticNetParam=0.0, 
tol=1e-6, 
fitIntercept=True, 
threshold=0.5, 
thresholds=None, 
probabilityCol="probability", 
rawPredictionCol="rawPrediction", 
standardization=True, 
weightCol=None, 
aggregationDepth=2, 
family="auto")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you point out the unmatched parameters between two classes? It seems to be matched though they have different parameter names.

Comment: for example the scikit model has a parameter called "penalty" which defaults to "l2". However, i cant find the same parameter in the pyspark model implementation. Another exmaple would be the parameter "aggregationDepth" in the pyspark model - its missing in scikit's implementation

Comment: @frankyjuang pls see my updated question where included a list of the parameters of each model

Comment: For `penalty` in scikit, set `elasticNetParam` in pyspark to match the setting. And `aggregationDepth` doesn't usually make difference to the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By now I figured out that as indicated by the parameter `standardization=True` pyspark does standardize the data within the model whereas scikit doesn't. Implementing `preprocessing.scale`before applying the scikit model gave me close matching results for both models

Answer (score 7):

pyspark's LR uses ElasticNet regularization, which is a weighted sum of L1 and L2 terms; weight is `elasticNetParam`. So with `elasticNetParam=0` you get L2 regularization, and `regParam` is L2 regularization coefficient; with `elasticNetParam=1` you get L1 regularization, and `regParam` is L1 regularization coefficient. `C` in sklearn LogisticRegression is inverse of `regParam`, i.e. `regParam = 1/C`.

Also, default training methods are different; you may need to set solver='lbfgs' in sklearn LogisticRegression to make training methods more similar. It only works with L2 though.

If you need ElasticNet regularization (i.e. 0 < elasticNetParam < 1), then sklearn implements it in [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) - set `loss='elasticnet'`, `alpha` would be similar to `regParam` (and you don't have to inverse it, like C), and `l1_ratio` would be `elasticNetParam`.

sklearn doesn't provide threshold directly, but you can use predict_proba instead of predict, and then apply the threshold yourselves.

Disclaimer: I have zero spark experience, the answer is based on sklearn and spark docs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! Do you also know how to take care of the parameter "aggregationDepth"?

Comment: AFAIK aggregationDepth is a parameter of parallelization method used in Spark; it shouldn't have much (if any?) impact on quality, but may have an impact on training speed.

Comment: SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='elasticnet') and also adjust `alpha` `l1_ratio` and max sure that `n_iter` is large enough in sklearn 0.18.2 or earlier.