# Logistic regression: Issue obtain same coefficients with PySpark mllib and statsmodel

Tags: pyspark, classification, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am interested to have statistics summary as obtained in statsmodel, while using pyspark. I am new to pyspark. As a first step, I tried to run logistic regression using statstmodel and pyspark, to match the intercept and coefficients. However I get them different.

**Common part for both:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/bank.csv"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ml-bank').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv(file_location, header = True, inferSchema = True)
temp_table_name = "bank_csv"
df.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)
numeric_features = [t[0] for t in df.dtypes if t[1] == 'int']

from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler

categoricalColumns = ['marital' ]
stages = []
for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = categoricalCol, outputCol = categoricalCol + 'Index')
    encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categoricalCol + 
   "classVec"])
   stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]
label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'deposit', outputCol = 'label')
stages += [label_stringIdx]
numericCols = ['age', 'balance']
assemblerInputs = [c + "classVec" for c in categoricalColumns] + numericCols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
df = pipelineModel.transform(df)
selectedCols = ['label', 'features'] + cols
df = df.select(selectedCols)
```

**Separate content starts: For Mllib:**

```
#Test train split
train, test = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed = 2018)

from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'label', 
maxIter=10,standardization=False,regParam=0.0,elasticNetParam=1)
lrModel = lr.fit(train)
predict_train=lrModel.transform(train)
predict_test=lrModel.transform(test)

print("Coefficients: " + str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(lrModel.intercept))
```

*It gives an output of coefficient and intercept as:*

*Coefficients: [-0.15224852297849636,0.4353532847935295,0.01418389527062097,4.6707000626430065e-05]*

*Intercept: -0.8298919632117885*

**Now statsmodel is used to find the coeffcient and intercept as follows:**

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df2=df_stats.toPandas()

m1 = smf.logit(

       formula='label ~  C(maritalIndex) + age+ balance',
       data=df2) \
       .fit()
m1.summary()
```

*[The intercept is obtained as seen in the image in this link:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1IeC.png)*
The intercept is -1.0338. Similarly other coefficient are different from that from mllib (pyspark).

**What did I try**

- Setting regularization to L1 (elasticNetParam=1) with regParam=0. This is to check if its something
  related to regularization. The intention was to turn of regularization as discussed in
  [Replicate logistic regression model from pyspark in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612873/replicate-logistic-regression-model-from-pyspark-in-)
  scikit-learn

Could someone help me to find why I get different intercept and coefficients with **pyspark.ml.classification** and **statstmodel**.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check that the created design matrix is the same, e.g. do you have the same encoding for the categorical variable in both cases and no standardization?

Comment: As you suggested @Josef I checked the code with 
1.Only numerical columns-->both methods give same result
2.Categorical column only one at a time--> The design matrix seems to be different as pyspark creates the matrix using onehotencoder, while statsmodel does it direct. I created a dummy variable for statsmodel, so that design matrix looks similar to that in pyspark.
The output of intercept and coefficient are close by (differ at the 2nd decimal point). Couldnt get closer than that.
Thank you

Comment: Addition of more categories results in change in design matrix. Can anyone suggest how to have similar design matrix as output from onehotencoder (pyspark) as from statsmodels